# How can I prevent the default event action when an event handler is attached to a parent HTML element?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have alot of links on my page that I want to be ajaxified so that when I click the link, it deletes the item, so I attached and event handler  to a parent div like so:

```
<div id="parent">
   <a href='#' data-itemid='1'>Delete Me</a>
   <a href='#' data-itemid='2'>Delete Me</a>
   <a href='#' data-itemid='3'>Delete Me</a>
</div>
```

And I used the following JQuery

```
  $('#parent').delegate('a', 'ajax:beforeSend', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('a')) {
      var itemid = target.attr('data-itemid');
      $.post("/item/"+itemid+'.json', {
        _method: 'delete'
      });
    }
  })
  .live('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var itemid = data + '';
    console.log(itemid);
    $('item-' + itemid + '-content').fadeOut();
  });
```

The problem is that when I click the link, the POST gets submitted and my page receives the response, however the event.preventDefault() line does not seem to be working, because the click event goes through and sends a second GET request to reload my page.

How can I prevent this page reload from happening?  I am using JQuery 1.5.1, and Rails 3.0.7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, haven't tried it but try adding `return false;` to the end of the beforeSend anonymous function.

```
  $('#parent').delegate('a', 'ajax:beforeSend', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('a')) {
      var itemid = target.attr('data-itemid');
      $.post("/item/"+itemid+'.json', {
        _method: 'delete'
      });
    }
    return false;
  })
```

Comment: Well, see... the thing is, if I do that, or if I use event.stopPropagation(), it will stop the GET request from happening, but for some reason it also stops the ajax:success from executing as well (which usually executes normally after the erroneous GET request)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with the delegate() function, but it doesn't look like you're sending the click event, which is the default operation you're looking to avoid.

Looking on the jQuery documentation, delegate() is a relative of live(): http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

So I might try something like...

```
$('#parent a').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var itemid = $(this).attr('data-itemid');

    $.post("/item/"+itemid+'.json', {
      _method: 'delete'
    });
  })
...
```

Comment: I expected this to work, but now it sends the GET before the POsT..  this could be though, because Rails hijacks the click event, that's why I was using the ajax:beforeSend

Comment: Christian is right, for event.preventDefault() to work you would need to bind/delegate to the 'click' event. However you may be able to work around this by using your existing delegate function with an additional bind function to catch the click event, calling event.preventDefault() within this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this wasn't the "Rails" way to delete an item via an AJAX link.  Instead of handling the ajax setup manually, you can use a construct similar to the following eyesore

```
link_to 'Delete Item', @item, :'data-itemid' => item.id, :class => 'delete-item-link', :remote => true, :'data-method' => :delete, :'data-type' => :json
```

Then to remove the item from the page, and handle the json response from the controller:

```
  $('#parent').delegate('a', 'ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var itemid = data + '';
    $('#item-' + itemid + '-content').fadeOut();
  });
```

That accomplishes the end goal I set out for.  That said, it doesn't actually answer my original question, so I'd appreciate any further input.

Apparently I've also seen that there are issues with chaining and '.live()' on JQuery, that don't exist with '.delegate()'

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html

Don't know how accurate that is still